# WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch <clkDiv/counter_1> has a constant value of 0 in block <DAC>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx

I received a warning like this:

---

```
WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch <clkDiv/counter_1> has a constant value of 0 in block <DAC>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch <clkDiv/counter_1> has a constant value of 0 in block <DAC>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch <clkDiv/counter_1> has a constant value of 0 in block <DAC>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch <clkDiv/counter_1> has a constant value of 0 in block <DAC>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
```

Is there something wrong in my code? thanks!

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity DAC is
    port(
        CLK: in std_logic;
        CLK2: inout std_logic;
        CS: out std_logic;
        MOSI: out std_logic
    );
end DAC;

architecture behavioral of DAC is
    signal reg : std_logic_vector (23 downto 0) :="100001100011100000000001";
    signal counter_G : integer range 0 to 24 := 0;
    signal CS_S : std_logic := '1';
    signal mosi_S : std_logic := '0';
    constant DELAY:integer := 2; 
begin
    clkDiv : entity work.ClockDivider(Behavioral) 
        generic map(DELAY => DELAY)
        port map (CLK, CLK2);        

    Senddata : process(CLK2, counter_G) 
    begin
        if falling_edge(CLK2) then
            counter_G <= counter_G + 1;
            if counter_G <24 then    
                CS_S <= '0';
                mosi_S <= reg(23);
                reg <= reg(22 downto 0) & reg(23);
            else
               CS_S <= '1';
               counter_G <=0;
            end if;        
        end if;
    end process Senddata;

    CS <= CS_S;
    MOSI <= mosi_S;
end behavioral;
```

---

---

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity ClockDivider is
    GENERIC (DELAY: integer := 16 );
    PORT 
    ( 
        CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
        CLK_OUT : out  STD_LOGIC := '0'
    );
end ClockDivider;

architecture Behavioral of ClockDivider is
begin    
    process(CLK)
        variable counter : integer range 0 to DELAY := 0;
    begin
        if(CLK'event AND CLK='1') then
            counter := counter + 1;
            if counter = DELAY / 2 then
                CLK_OUT <= '0';
            elsif counter = DELAY then
                counter := 0;
                CLK_OUT <= '1';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: I received a warning like this:FF/Latch has a constant value of 0 in block . This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process. is there something wrong in my code? thanks!

Comment: You got the code for the clock divider module?

Comment: Issue is likely inside the clkDiv entity (ClockDivider). This may or may not be a real problem, depending on the design. One or more of the FF/Latch described by that HDL code always have the value 0 regardless of any input. If those are just extra bits in a generic clock prescaler that might be tolerable, but if they are important bits expected to be toggling, then your code does have a design problem. Impossible to tell without looking at the code.

Comment: The problem is in entity clkdiv so post that in your question. Also, don't put more question in a comment - edit your question and put it there. Please make those changes and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an `inout` type for `CLK2`. Either use VHDL-2008, or use a temporary variable.

Then `counter` is likely to be reset to 0 every time the clock divider process triggers. Don't use variables like this: use signals instead. E.g.

```
architecture Behavioral of ClockDivider is
    signal counter : natural range 0 to DELAY := 0;
begin    
    clk_div_proc: process(CLK)
    begin
        if rising_edge(CLK) then
            if counter < DELAY then
                counter <= counter + 1;
            else
                counter <= 0;
            end if;
            if counter < DELAY/2 then
                CLK_OUT <= '1';
            else
                CLK_OUT <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```